# Bridging the Gap Between Implicit Understanding and Formal Math

Tags: elementary-set-theory, learning

I use set theory on an implicit basis as a programmer; however, it's recently become necessary for me to expand into the formal world to explain my intent to decision makers that don't operate at a software engineering level.

If I have a set of data, called $R$, and it represents a set of equally sized tuples.  How would I represent the formula of a second set derived from the elemnets of $R$, where some of the values represent 'groups' from the elements of the tuples within $R$?

An example: I have a list of customer cars as a dataset.  And I want to represent a set $D$ which is all of the customer vehicles that are of the Dodge Brand.  Doing this algorithmically with a high level programming language with integrated query is a snap, but I don't know how to put it into a formula.

Naturally this will be further subdivided to represent the logical path on how a decision is reached, such as the times a particular customer has brought their vehicle in, the invoices would be such a sub set. This example is a bit contrived, because I can't really divulge the full story due to confidentiality concerns.

This also needs to take into consideration that multiple sets might be used to construct a final result, of which some of the data elements might overlap (such as Vehicle IDs being represented as elements of other sets of tuples.)

Any help?

Edit:
I've been working on what I think may describe some of the sets and I wondered if I had the notation right, as follows:
$$
R = \left \{ r_{1}, r_{2}, ..., r_{n} \right \} 
$$
$n \overset{\underset{\mathrm{def}}{ }}{=}$ Total Item Count
$$
r_{j} = \left ( T_{t}, T_{s}, D_{G}, S, M, V, B \mid \left\{\begin{matrix} T_{t} \in \mathbb{R},\\ T_{s} \in \mathbb{R},\\ D_{G} : DATE\\1 \leq S \leq 10\\M \in \mathbb{Z} \\ V \in \left \{ Active, Inactive, Trail, Drop  \right \} \\B \in \mathbb{Z} \end{matrix}\right. \right ) \mid \left \{  \right.1 \leq j \leq n 
$$

Comment: Sounds like you're interested in the mathematical underpinnings of relational database theory. See http://en.m.wikibooks.org/wiki/Relational_Database_Design/Basic_Concepts

Comment: My issue isn't understanding how a relational database works.  My issue is understanding the formal world of how to explain it to someone, where it isn't acceptable, for me providing the answer, to point them to how a database works.  I need the opposite of that, how the formal world of math works on over the notion of set theory.  Also, the example was contrived because I have to show proof of how a decision is reached.  Some of the operations occur after the database (due to tooling limits, and/or simplicity of workflow.)  I'm using a GUI over a database which kind of stinks functionally.

Comment: The only reason I didn't change the tag on this question and on the previous question you asked is that I don't know what should be. Set theory it's not. Because not everything which includes sets is considered set theory.

Comment: I presume you already know how a RD works. The reference wasn't meant to teach you that. It was meant to be a tool to help you reexamine what you already know from a mathematical perspective. That's what I think you were asking about. You can't hope to explain it with expertise to someone else until you understand it yourself. One often finds that, in mathematical studies, the same topic reappears over and over. Don't make the mistake of assuming you already know it--the topic should be familiar, but presented from a different perspective. Focus on the new perspective, not the familiarity.

Comment: The decision makers where I operate are well educated and leave me to get the answers they want, but aren't afraid to question the decision made if they don't see a clear logical path.  The goal is to bridge the gap between my lack of verbal finesse and their understanding of finance, business management, and highly audited environments.  I can't simply say 'I had to weight the data because it didn't add up otherwise.'  They want all the details because the information might be used for projections, decision making, and budgeting.

Comment: I understand why I might introduce a weight into an equation, due to a subset representing a partial time slice of the whole and the formulas of their original report don't take such a thing into account.  I want to know how to formalize the concepts to help me work more efficiently, and in learning a new way to look at the problems, it might help me move forward in tougher tasks if I can represent it in something other than a thought.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a set of triplets $R:=\{(x_1,y_1,z_1),\ldots, (x_n, y_n, z_n)\}$, then you can denote the subset of triplets with the second coordinate equaling $5$ by
$$D:=\{(x,y,z) \in R \mid y=5\}.$$
If you want to further whittle it down to the ones where the first coordinate is between $0$ and $1$, you can write it as a subset of $R$ or as a subset of $D$.
$$\{(x,y,z) \in R \mid y=5, 0\le x \le 1\} = \{(x,y,z) \in D \mid 0 \le x \le 1\}.$$

---

In some texts/papers, I've sometimes seen data represented like $R:= \{\mathbf{x}_1, \ldots, \mathbf{x}_n\}$, with each $\mathbf{x}_i$ representing a $k$-tuple $\mathbf{x}_i=(x_i^{(1)}, \ldots, x_i^{(k)})$, so the notation can get messy sometimes...

Comment: I've added an edit to the main question about the description of the tuples.  The data is simple but describing it seems to be convoluted.  Is the means to describing the sub-elements of R accurate?